# What is the state of domestic Israeli opposition to the - alleged - Israeli interference to aid supply in Gaza?

Tags: israel, 2023-israel-hamas-war, gaza

We've recently - March 2024 - seen numerous Western government leaders, normally pro-Israel, express alarm at the food situation in Gaza.

The World Bank (no, not one of those mistrusted-by-Israel UN organs), has also weighed in with some [serious alarm](https://www.worldbank.org/en/news/statement/2024/03/19/world-bank-group-statement-on-gaza).

> With more than half the population of Gaza on the brink of famine—including children and the elderly—the World Bank Group calls for urgent action to save lives. We join the international community in calling for immediate, free, and unimpeded access of medical supplies, food and life-essential services through all available means at speed and scale to the people of Gaza.”

Most of those statements tiptoe around blaming Israel directly, but many of them request unimpeded aid access from the Israeli government.

With that in mind, what is the state of the (Jewish) `*` domestic Israeli opposition to Israeli government policies concerning Gaza aid?

I could see three broad domestic concerns about this war.

1. support, or opposition, to the wider military operations to remove Hamas
2. concern with how the government is getting the hostages back
3. opposition to aid policies.

Really, I am only concerned with 3. here.  There is a traditional pro-peace constituency that can be counted on to generally oppose wars.  But I am wondering if there are any influential, non-pacifist, pushback about - again, alleged - Israeli shortcomings in allowing food aid.

Either for ethical reasons, or just out of self-interested concern at the risk of Israel's losing support from Western countries?

Any large scale protests, prominent politicians or even media voicing concerns about #3?

p.s. I recall one comment on a previous post of mine that there were mass protests in Israel, but did those concern the food emergency specifically?

`*` Arab Israelis' positions with regards to this war are more complex and nuanced than many would assume, but this question is really only asking about Jewish Israeli public opinion.  Like that of pacifists, Arab-Israeli opposition would seem a lot less exceptional.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [(MARCH 22, 2024) NPR article](https://www.npr.org/2024/03/22/1240108446/experts-say-gaza-faces-imminent-famine-israel-says-that-is-a-myth), rather limited:

> INSKEEP: I recognize we're in a world where everybody has their own sources and to some extent their own view of reality, so how does the Israeli public view hunger in Gaza?

> ESTRIN: I've been speaking about that with Israelis along the Gaza border this week, and I heard a range of reactions from flat out denial to people saying, I have no sympathy for anyone hungry in Gaza after the October 7 attack. A common response I've heard is Hamas is stealing the food.

> A former senior official on military law told me Israel, quote, "cannot dodge responsibility." He said starvation is a war crime. And wherever the military has conquered Gaza, it has a responsibility in that area to make sure civilians are fed. **But you are hearing very few prominent Israeli voices saying this kind of thing out loud. There was a centrist politician who said Israel was starving Gaza, and she faced such a huge backlash that she had to walk it back.** And this week, a leading Arab lawmaker in Israel, Ayman Odeh, was speaking about this in parliament. And this is what happened.

> ESTRIN: He was saying there, there's slaughter and there's starvation in Gaza. And he was actually dragged off the podium.

[Jerusalem Post](https://www.jpost.com/breaking-news/article-792895) covered Ayman Oden's removal.

p.s. I'd be more interested in who the "centrist politician" was, but haven't much luck finding that out.